# jQuery grabbing wrong form when using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php function that loops thru matches in a database, inside the loop, there is a form that gets returned to the page where the function is called:

```
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($get_unconfirmed))  
{ 
echo "<form name='confirm_appointment' method='post' class='confirm_appointment'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='app_id' value='$appointment_id'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='clinic_id' value='$clinic_id'>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' class='update_appointment_button' value='$appointment_id'></td>";    
        echo "</form>"; 
}
```

Then I have jQuery to submit the form:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".update_appointment_button").click(function(){
        var url = "ajax/update_appointment_status.php";
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $(".confirm_appointment").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                   alert(data); // show response from the php script.
               }
             });
        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
});
```

But the issue is, the way its set up, no matter what row I push "submit" for - I always get the values from the last row (form).

So I know the issue, I am not telling jQuery to get the values from the form with the button thats pushed. I need to somehow use .this maybe, but just cant seem to figure out the correct syntax.

Any help would be appricated!

Comment: All your forms get the same class. Your forms get processed with serialize, but will be overwritten each time. leaving you with the last one. You will need to make your forms unique.

Comment: -> @Ding is showing you a relative way to grab the form holding the activated submit button. In another scenario you can use the `id` of your database record to help you with making that form unique. The idea is to grab just one form, instead of all forms at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can access its parent form like this

```
data: $(this).closest(".confirm_appointment").serialize(),
```

or something like this

```
data: $this.parent().parent().serialize(),
```

Comment: When changing - data: $(".confirm_appointment").serialize(), to data: $(this).closest(".confirm_appointment").serialize(), -  The data is empty

Comment: That's because your HTML is invalid - you need to wrap the whole table in the `form` element.

Comment: Roy - Thank you, can you elaborate just a little more?

Comment: Thank you Roy... That made sense. I gave the button and the form a matching data set and ended up with       data: $("." + form_data).serialize(),.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: replace the button `click` event by the form `submit` event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.confirm_appointment').submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var url = "ajax/update_appointment_status.php";
        var serialized = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: serialized,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data); // show response from the php script.
            }
        });
    });
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/gs3pgyvf/)</kbd>